# Remove tracked file from Git when file has $$ in name

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to remove a file from my Git repository: `~$$ClassDiagram.~vsdx`

I tried to remove it

`git rm --cached "~$$ClassDiagram.~vsdx"`

resulting in

`fatal: pathspec '~4192ClassDiagram.~vsdx' did not match any files`

The $$ turned into 4192. How can I delete this file from my repository so it no longer shows in the remote on Github?

Comment: `$$` expands to the numeric process id of the current process (your shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shell specific problem rather than a git problem. Assuming that your shell is Bash, use single quotes instead, since no variable substitution takes place inside them:

```
git rm --cached '~$$ClassDiagram.~vsdx'
```

Comment: Great; I suggest adding the "bash" tag to your post, then :-)